# need help Setting QoS via command line (telnet or ssh)

Tags: networking, dd-wrt

I have read on this post: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1047158#1047158 that "QoS on the DD-WRT is broken via GUI" i need help setting up Services Priority, Interface Priority, Netmask Priority, etc trought telnet or ssh, please i need help

also after trying htb/fq_codel, discovered that it is not giving me full ul speed (does not work as supposed to),then tried codel and pie, found they work as intended, however when i tried to enable TCP-Packet Priority (SYN, FIN, RST), Services Priority and some Netmask Priority im not able to access my home server (http and ftp). also  im trying to use htb/pie under qos because i discovered/think that it is more efficient than fq_codel but now it has messed all up, because i can not access my home server (http). ftp is not working as well, please help

Comment: DD-WRT has a pretty good forum base, don't forget you need to ID which version router and firmware you're on or have tried.  "help" for "help" callers comes best to those who provide details on stuff they've tried.

Comment: im sorry im just a lillte desperate, but here is some info, hope it helps. Router Information

System
Router NameDD-WRT
Router ModelLinksys E2500
Firmware Version DD-WRT v3.0-r30631 mega (09/14/16)
Kernel VersionLinux 3.10.103 #14213 Wed Sep 14 13:08:06 CEST 2016 mips

Comment: While adding the detail here is great, I really meant for your DD forum post.  You'll be ignored there, because you haven't given detail.